# Do I need to provide sentences for training Spacy NER or are paragraphs fine?

Tags: nlp, python-3.5, spacy

I am trying to train a new Spacy model to recognize references to law articles. I start using a blank model, and train the ner pipe according to the example given in the documentation.

The performance of the trained model is really poor, even with several thousands on input points. I am tryong to figure out why.

One possible answer is that I am giving full paragraphs to train on, instead of sentences that are in the examples. Each of these paragraphs can have multiple references to law articles. Is this a possible issue?

Turns out I was making a huge mistake in my code. There is nothing wrong with paragraphs. As long as your code actually supplies them to spacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paragraphs should be fine. Could you give an example input data point?